# Generating JAXB classes with multiple prefixes using an external binding

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2, xjc

I have a group of XSD files, as follows:

- http://www.iana.org/assignments/xml-registry/schema/contact-1.0.xsd
- http://www.iana.org/assignments/xml-registry/schema/domain-1.0.xsd
- http://www.iana.org/assignments/xml-registry/schema/epp-1.0.xsd
- http://www.iana.org/assignments/xml-registry/schema/eppcom-1.0.xsd
- http://www.iana.org/assignments/xml-registry/schema/host-1.0.xsd

Most of them are dependent on each other, so I created the following catalog file to allow the JAXB compiler (XJC) to generate the classes.

```
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
    <public publicId="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:contact-1.0" uri="contact-1.0.xsd"/>
    <public publicId="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0" uri="domain-1.0.xsd"/>
    <public publicId="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0" uri="epp-1.0.xsd"/>
    <public publicId="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:eppcom-1.0" uri="eppcom-1.0.xsd"/>
    <public publicId="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:host-1.0" uri="host-1.0.xsd"/>
    <public publicId="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:rgp-1.0" uri="rgp-1.0.xsd"/>
</catalog>
```

Unfortunately, there are some collisions between some of the generated class names, which I must resolve - according to some research I need to create an external bindings file.

**I would like to prefix all classes that are *directly* generated from each XSD.**

Imported XSDs should be ignored (e.g. epp-1.0 imports eppcom-1.0.xsd), since they will already be generated if I repeat the process for each XSD. (i.e. prefix by XSD namespace if possible)

**Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?**

Since the XSD files are maintained by a 3rd party, I do not have the option of modifying the XSDs directly. I have tried the following external binding, but it does not work:

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.0"
              xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:bindings scd="x-schema:epp" node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:nameXmlTransform>
                <jxb:typeName prefix="Epp" />
                <jxb:elementName prefix="Epp" />
                <jxb:modelGroupName prefix="Epp" />
                <jxb:anonymousTypeName prefix="Epp" />
            </jxb:nameXmlTransform>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings scd="x-schema:eppcom" node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:nameXmlTransform>
                <jxb:typeName prefix="EppCom" />
                <jxb:elementName prefix="EppCom" />
                <jxb:modelGroupName prefix="EppCom" />
                <jxb:anonymousTypeName prefix="EppCom" />
            </jxb:nameXmlTransform>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Output:

```
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] XPath evaluation of "/xs:schema" results in empty target node
line 4 of file:/C:/Users/Jin%20Kim/workspace/registry/server/src/main/resources/xsd/bindings.xjb

[ERROR] XPath evaluation of "/xs:schema" results in empty target node
line 14 of file:/C:/Users/Jin%20Kim/workspace/registry/server/src/main/resources/xsd/bindings.xjb

Failed to parse a schema.
```

Comment: What happens without specifying the 'node' attributes? Is that necessary?

Comment: @Jin did you finally manage to generate code?